# Which signal is sent to a process after pipe is closed

Tags: php, linux, signals

I run a `foreignprogram` and pipe the output to `outputcatcher`. The commands are executed like this:

`$ foreignprogram | outputcatcher`

And I would like to handle exit of `foreignprogram` in `outputcatcher`. When  `foreignprogram` exits, the `outputcatcher` exits as well. Is there any signal that `outputcatcher` receives so I can handle it? I tried SIGINT, SIGTERM and SIGHUP but so far no luck.

The `ouputcatcher` is written in PHP if that matters and I handle the signals with pcntl_signal()

Comment: Don't you getting a standard input read error in `outputcatcher` when `foreignprogram` exit?

Answer (score 0):

I think these two programs are two independent programs.

There is no way for `foreignprogram` to know who is receiving my output as its input. Unless you implement is trickily.

But if you know `foreignprogram` pid then,

One thing you can do is you can check every second if `foreignprogram` is running or not, from `outputcatcher`. And if not running then you may like to exit your `outputcatcher`.

Try to send signal number `0` from `outputcatcher` every second and check return value.

I am not sure how to do this in PHP. But I think same will done as following in `bash`.

`kill -s 0 foreignpgram_pid`

This will check if `foreignpgram_pid` is running or not.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, although I was looking for some more "instant" method. Also I don't want to fiddle with PIDs.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this workaround:

`$ foreignprogram | outputcatcher && exitcatcher`

The `exitcatcher` gets executed when the `outputcatcher` exits, which means the `foreignprogram` exited. Not really an elegant solution, but works. I won't accept this answer, still waiting for the real one I asked for:)

In real life, I want to start process, parse its STDERR and publish it to RabbitMQ. The `outputcatcher` and `exitcatcher` is the same script, which accepts first parameter as command and second as the identification of the watched process. Something like this:

`$ foreignprogram 2>&1 > /dev/null | catcher output 'foreignProgram' && catcher exit 'foreignProgram'`

Comment: with `2>&1 > /dev/null` you are going to receive any stdout or stderr.

Comment: Despite the order of parameters, I receive only STDERR not STDOUT. I have tested this, it works. If I would exchange the parameters to `>/dev/null 2>&1` I wouldn't receive anything at all